# On aws, do I need to backup both EC2 instance and EBS volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

On aws using aws backup, do I need to backup both EC2 instance and EBS volume?
I see that my instance backup is 10GB so it looks like it contains the volume data but tbh I'm not sure I understand the instance vs volume difference well.

Comment: Having not used AWS Backup yet, my take is an instance backup is metadata about the EC2 instance (size, IP address, etc) as well as the EBS volumes. Whether it's all the EBS volumes or just the root volume, I'm not sure. Do a restore, that will give you an answer. A regular and scheduled restore test (monthly, annual, etc) is a critical part of any backup process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an AWS tutorial on [using AWS Backup to backup an EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/amazon-ec2-backup-and-restore-using-aws-backup/):

> When you back up an EC2 instance, AWS Backup will protect all Amazon EBS volumes attached to the instance, and will attach them to an AMI that stores all parameters from the original EC2 instance (excluding Elastic Inference accelerators and user data scripts).

Answer (score 0):

An EBS snapshot is a backup of a single EBS volume. The EBS snapshot contains all the data stored on the EBS volume at the time the EBS snapshot was created.

An AMI image is a backup of an entire EC2 instance. Associated with an AMI image are EBS snapshots. Those EBS snapshots are the backups of the individual EBS volumes attached to the EC2 instance at the time the AMI image was created.

Comment: So if I backup an instance I do not need to backup its root volume?

Comment: no, if you take backup of instance, you don't need to backup an EBS volume.

Comment: This answer refers to EBS snapshots and AMI images, rather than the AWS Backup service which the question asks about. The information given looks correct, but maybe not quite answering the question.